# How to manage simultaneous updates to the same database row in Web API 2 / Entity Framework project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have designed a Web API using C# and the .NET Framework 4.5.2.

One of the business objects within my solution holds a **balance** and this object maps directly to a table in my database. I'm using Entity Framework 6 within my data model project to access the database.

Each time the balance is updated an associated **transaction** needs to be created (a separate business object mapped to another database table), but only if the balance updates successfully.

Given the above, I am wrapping the updating of the balance and creation of the associated transaction in a SQL transaction using 'TransactionScope' currently.

My question is;

- How do I preserve the integrity of the balance and prevent the
  balance from dropping below zero whenever multiple clients are
  accessing my API?

If I check the balance will not drop below zero before updating the balance by getting the row from the database and checking the balance in the C# code, there's still a chance that another client will reduce the balance just after my check. I believe Web API client calls are asynchronous?

I think I need to somehow lock the database row I'm updating until the transaction has completed i.e. from the moment of my initial balance check until the balance has been updated and the associated transaction has been posted successfully.

If the first thing I did in my 'TransactionScope' was something like the SQL below, would the 'Accounts' table be locked until the end of the transaction if I set an appropriate Isolation Level for the transaction?

```
IF (SELECT Balance FROM Accounts WHERE ID = 1) >= 40
    UPDATE Accounts SET Balance = Balance - 40 WHERE ID = 1
```

What would happen if the first line in the if statement check above ran and another transaction reduced the balance just after the if check? Then the second line in the above SQL ran and reduced the balance to a value below zero? Is this possible or does SQL Server ensure that an if check like the above is always valid until the if statement block has completed? Or does this also depend on the SQL transaction Isolation Level? This part is a key concept that need to understand.

Since I'm using the Entity Framework I'd also like to avoid having to run a manual SQL statement like the above if possible. Is it possible to achieve the same thing using Entity Framework / LINQ alone?

One more thing to note is that if a client call would drop the balance below zero I'm planning to return an appropriate HTTP response code which the client can act on accordingly. The nature of my business object means that there should only ever be one person updating the balance at a time, but there is still a chance that the same row could be updated 'simultaneously', so I need to account for that possibility.

Comment: `If the first thing I did in my 'TransactionScope' was something like the SQL below, would the 'Accounts' table be locked until the end of the transaction if I set an appropriate Isolation Level for the transaction?` Yes, that's the whole point of isolation levels. In your case you need `Repeatable Read`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378149(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I found the link very helpful. Do you know if there is a way to hold a lock on the row I'm updating using Entity Framework directly, whilst still running the if check as part of the SQL query. I believe I can pump a custom SQL query through Entity Framework, but just wondered if that was my only option. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You might want to read up on column type: rowversion - you can read it but not set it and it changes anytime your row is changed.  If you use that in combination with your PK, you'll ensure your row is not changed between read and write.